# trying to print the a key variable in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsp

guys i am newbie so please help me .. i am trying to print variable key in json .. but it doesn't work .. here is my code

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="constructJson(document.getElementById(" name "))">Click Me!</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function constructJson(jsonKey) {
      var jsonObj = {
        "key1": "5"
      };
      jsonObj[jsonKey] = "2";
      alert(jsonObj);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your `jsonKey` argument is an element, an actual DOM node, probably not what you want to use as a key for an object. Also, there's a mismatch in quotes in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have double quotes inside double quotes and you should use value of input not DOM node:

```
onclick="constructJson(document.getElementById('name').value)"
```

and you need to set the id for input:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
```

to show JSON you need to use JSON.stringify:

```js
function constructJson(jsonKey){
 var jsonObj = {"key1": "5"};
   jsonObj[jsonKey] = "2";
   alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="constructJson(document.getElementById('name').value)" >Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to separate the code from html:

```js
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', constructJson, false);
}
function constructJson(eleName) {
  var jsonKey = document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value.trim();
  if (jsonKey.length == 0) {
    alert('insert a name');
    document.getElementsByName('name')[0].focus();
    return;
  }
  var jsonObj = {
    "key1": "5"
  };
  jsonObj[jsonKey] = "2";
  alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj, 4, 4));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name">
<button type="button" id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="constructJson(document.getElementById('name').value)">Click Me!</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function constructJson(jsonKey) {
        var jsonObj = {
            "key1": "5"
        };
        jsonObj[jsonKey] = "2";
        console.log(jsonObj);
        alert('{"key1":"5","'+jsonKey+'":"2"}');
        alert(jsonObj);
    }
</script>
</body>
```